# Accepting NULLS into Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got the below stored procedure that is very simple, but it allows NULL values to be passed in.

I'm just wondering what best practice is here, and how to deal with NULLs in cases such as this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClient]
    @ClientID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ......
    FROM
        Client
    WHERE
        ClientID = @ClientID
```

Comment: The procedure as posted looks like it will throw an error if you try to pass a null value.

Comment: The sp runs fine with a NULL value.

Comment: The query will never return a row when a `NULL` value is provided since a compare with `NULL` is never true. It looks like ClientID may be the primary key, in which case NULLs are not allowed anyway. Do you want to raise an error when a NULL is provided?

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, yes I was aware I could raise an error, but was just curious what others did in a similiar situation. That's correct that ClientID is the primary key.

Comment: "What others do in a similar situation" depends on their business rules for that specific case.   Do you have a business rule for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to just declare the argument as `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClient] (
    @ClientID int NOT NULL
)
. . .
```

However, that is not quite allowed for all stored procedures.

Your stored procedure is fine.  If a `NULL` value is passed in, then it will return no rows.  This seems reasonable, because `ClientId` is probably never `NULL` in the `Client` table, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: Defining it as NULL throws this error: Msg 11555, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetClient, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 7]
The parameter '@ClientID' has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except for inline table-valued functions.

Comment: That's correct. ClientID is the primary key on the table. I just wondered what was concerned best practice in cases such as this.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise a custom error:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClient]
    @ClientID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @ClientID is null 
    BEGIN
          raiserror('The value for ClientID should not be null', 15, 1)
          return;
    END
    SELECT
        ......
    FROM
        Client
    WHERE
        ClientID = @ClientID
END
```

Comment: terminate by `return` else it will go to `select..`

Comment: @YogeshSharma : Return added to stop SP to execute further, thanks for correction.

Comment: Without `begin`/`end` including the `return` ... .

Comment: Yeah, I would say this is probably the best way to handle this .. given the issue with "The parameter '@MyParameterIDontWantToBeNull has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except for inline table-valued functions."  I would call this (as it is in this answer) defensive coding.  Its a small holy war too, because a good datalayer (c#,java,etc) would watch for a null value and throw an exception there.  So how much validation should be in the stored procedure vs the calling application?  Opinions vary.