# error: parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure. One of the parameters ....

```
@ID int not null,
```

is giving me an error:

> NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules,
>   except for inline table-valued functions.

how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with your SP? Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532445/accepting-nulls-into-stored-procedures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict NULL as parameter to stored procedure SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330303/how-to-restrict-null-as-parameter-to-stored-procedure-sql-server)

Answer (score 6):

if you want to have `required` parameter for a stored procedure then just declare the parameter like below, then check whether param is null or not

```
Create procedure MyProc
@ID int
as
    if @ID is null
    begin
      -- handle the null case here
    end
--  rest of your query
```

If the parameter is optional then assign `null` to the parameter, which acts as a default value if no input is provided in procedure call

```
Create procedure MyProc
@ID int = null
as
--  your query
```

Comment: This will not stop you to pass `NULL` in the parameter, i.e. to call it like this `exec MyProc NULL`. So this isn't an answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an error if the parameter is null in the beginning of your SP

```
IF @ID IS NULL 
  BEGIN 
      RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1,'myProcedure'); 
  END
```